# Access elements of same class in reverse order

Tags: jquery

i have few elements with the class name `.paying-amount`. Using jquery i need to access them in reverse order

when i use `.each()` in the following way

```
$('.paying-amount').each(function () { $(this).html("hello"); })
```

i perform the function from 0...n. but i want to do it from n ... 0.

saving the `.paying-amount` elements in an array would solve the purpose as i can access the array in the reverse direction but somehow unable to manage it.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var len = $('.paying-amount').length
for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  $('.paying-amount').eq(i).html("hello")
}
```

USing the eq() selector, you can access the element by index.

Answer (score 2):

This was filed as a feature request for jQuery in the past, and it won't be implemented. Your question is answered in the [comments here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7411).

You can either do:

```
//get a plain array of elements then call reverse on that
$(something).get().reverse();
```

Or you can extend jQuery:

```
$.fn.reverse = Array.prototype.reverse
```

Then you will be able to call `reverse()` on the elements.

```
$('.paying-amount').reverse().each(function () { $(this).html("hello"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array you could use the following :

```
var classElements = [];
$('.paying-amount').each(function () { classElements.push($(this)); })
//finally reverse the array
classElements.reverse();
```